# "parent" seems a little ambiguous

Tags: discussion, status-completed, links, meta

I was just asking the question "I wonder if it would be useful having a link from meta SA to SA at the top." I didn't realise that "parent" was up there and meant the regular SA site.

'parent' in this case seems a little nondescript or ambiguous... is there a more descriptive link text that could be used here? (btw... No ambiguity with 'meta')

Comment: Me too. Took me weeks to find that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, there have been a number of requests for this from various network sites.. so I am changing it from

> parent

to

> main

Comment: Should this be `[status-completed]`?  I still see "parent" on my screen.

Comment: @aar it's checked into source control

Comment: Thanks, you guys are awesome <3